# How to let users connect their custom domains to my next.js app hosting on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js, custom-domain

I developed a next.js app where everyone can design his own profile page.

Today, everyone using a unique sub-domain like jake.app-name.com and ben.app-name.com.

I want to give everyone the option to connect his own domain to point to his profile page like jake.com.

I know how to manage it on the server after the domain is pointing to the server.

My question is how can I connect, using code (API) many domains to my google app engine without any limitation in the future? What is required? Google will manage all the SSL certificates automatically? I will have an additional cost?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you reviewed the requirements that Google imposes on proving you own/control a domain? AFAIK, there is no published API to accomplish that step.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into this in 2021 but as of last year this was not possible. You have to manually map each unique domain to one of your subdomains.

Regarding SSL certificates, note the following from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl)
....*If you are using subdomains, there is a limit of 20 managed certificates per week for each base domain*. ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And if I'm creating a wildcard? I mean *.my-domain.com. All of them will have a valid SSL immediately? And regarding my big question, let's take for example the company WIX, how do u think that they are doing that? How they create millions of subdomain and how do they let everyone connect their domain?

Comment: Same link in my answer says ....note that managed certificates do not support wildcard mappings..... Regarding your original question, the process is possible, just not on Google App Engine. This would mean that WIX or Shopify (who also do something similar) are not using Google App Engine

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. If not google, do u know which service allow such a thing like Wix and Shopify are doing?

Comment: I was referring to Google App Engine (not Google in general). You might be able to do it with Google Compute Engine but I'm not sure. You should also check the different offerings from AWS and Microsoft Azure